# Redirecting certain website paths to different webservers

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, iis-8, owncloud

Currently my primary web server is IIS8 on Server_2012r2 and I set up a secondary web server using Apache on CentOS that is running Own-cloud, is it possible to make it so when I type in www.mydomain.com it stays on the IIS server, but if I go to mydomain.com/owncloud/ it would forward that particular ULR to the Cent OS server?

Comment: You could use a Microsoft plugin called ARR to turn your IIS into a reverse web proxy if that is what you are after.

Comment: Im trying that, but at the current moment I can only seem to get it to forward all of the paths or none of the paths, ie it either sends all the traffic from mydomain.com and mydomain.com/owncloud/ to the apache server or the iis server, but what i need it to do is only forward the ulr for mydomain.com/owncloud/ and everything else should not be forwarded. Im sure this is probably operator error, but if you know a decent tutorial to show how to do what im trying to do that would be a big help.

Comment: I know I managed to do that about 2yrs ago, using the official docs, StackOverflow and Google. The URLrewrite module is involved I recall, it's similar to doing it with httpd really. I'm on vacation now however and don't have access to my archive.

Comment: I found the solution here at https://mendel129.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/iis-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-apache-and-wordpress/ seems my whole issues was resolved by adding the ^ in front of ^owncloud/(.*) .